# Arquillian - how to test Tomcat DataSource (initialcontext problems)

Tags: tomcat, jboss-arquillian

I'm trying to use Arquillian with the tomcat embed container, but having issues trying to get direct access to the tomcat-managed Datasource (my current usecase is to improve on the DataSourceFactory, but even basic java.sql calls to the JNDI managed datasource do not work).

There are references to @ArquillianResource InitialContext, but there isn't much around using this with Tomcat (which does *not* have an externally exposed JNDI).

Need to make this call:

```
DataSource ds = (DataSource)arquilliancontext.lookup("java:/comp/env/jdbc/MyDS");
```

And no matter what I have tried to date, keep getting nullpointers (when using ArquillianResource), or 'NoInitialContextException' with regular 'new InitialContext()',  when try either as a straight test, or as a CdiTestBean in the WebArchive.

```
WebArchive webArchive=  ShrinkWrap
.create(WebArchive.class, "ROOT.war")
...
.addAsManifestResource("normal_context.xml", "context.xml") //add managed datasource definition
```

Are there any Arquillian examples of how to use DataSource for testing in Tomcat (without JPA)?